# Is it possible to create redirects for moved files in a github repository?

Tags: redirect, github, move

I'm reorganizing a collection of documentation that is hosted as a github repository. Is there any way to create redirects in the repository so that anyone who has bookmarked a file that has moved is redirected to the new location?

Comment: How about just putting a link into the page at the old location, pointing to the new location?

Comment: Yeah, could do that but that would make the repo look like it has lots of duplicate files, which would be pretty frustrating to a newcomer to the docs, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to set up redirects for moved files. The next best thing to do depends on what you need?

- **Do you just want to avoid broken URLs?** Then distribute URLs that are more permanent. One way of doing that is locating the file you want to link to on GitHub, then pressing <kbd>y</kbd> which will replace the branch name with a commit SHA. For example, if you're at `https://github.com/fred/frobbler/blob/master/LICENSE.md` and then press <kbd>y</kbd>, you're browser will reload `https://github.com/fred/frobbler/blob/{commit-sha}/LICENSE.md`. Even if `LICENSE.md` were removed or renamed in later commits, that URL will stay valid. Of course, people will now be linked to a particular (historic) snapshot of that file.
- **Do you want to forward people to the latest version of the previous content?** In that case, you'll likely need to keep the old document around and put a notice in it where the new document can be found. Or, you use one of those URL abbreviation services to generate a public URL, which allows you to edit the actual URL later on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that automatically.

Server need to answer with `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` code. But GitHub is just serving pages.

Just put words in big font **`MOVED TO http://new.url`**